Dracaena marginata has brown spots
Can anyone tell me what these brown spots are? It has them on a few leaves and it looks spots are coming in on the new leaves as well. Is this leaf spot disease? I've sprayed with a copper fungicide sporadically but not sure if it is working. I am located in Iowa and the plant is in the interior corner of east facing large window room






See my answer here.  The too long don't read version is:

not enough light
too much water

This has allowed a virus/fungus/bacteria to start.  Plants can outgrow it if conditions improve.

move closer to the window
water less
consider repotting.  You can use the same pot, just put fresh soil in the bottom of the pot.


Thank you thank you! I just purchased a grow light to go above it and hoping it gets better
